# Clarifying composition relationships

Tags: design-patterns

I have read that for composition relationships, component objects must exist during the life cycle of the container, and the container deletion may destroy the component objects.

If there are three classes Home, Office and HomeOffice, can it be said that the relationship between HomeOffice and Home/Office is composition as without Home and office, HomeOffice cannot exist. I am unsure as I saw some conflicting answers on composition that the container deletion must destroy component objects.

Comment: Aggregation vs composition may give you some information but still I would want to suggest you : **Do not try to get too much involved with definations and differences like these**. Inheritance vs Aggregation is relevant as they both are different styles of reusing components but aggregation and composition relate to  same concept where an interface is exposed by an object while other object consumes it.

Comment: Are you asking in the context of UML or something else?

Comment: @jaco0646 I had this question when I was studying class relations in C++